# Apache/PHP won't allow for mod_rewrite in .htaccess files

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have a simple .htaccess file to rewrite `www.domain.com/foobar.php` to `www.domain.com/foobar`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule foobar foobar.php [L]
```

It is giving me a 404 even though I ran `phpinfo();` (which shows the `mod_rewrite` module), and checked `httpd.conf` (which uses `mod_rewrite` several times by default).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most possible reason for this is that you haven't set 'AllowOverride' to at least 'FileInfo' at your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set it to AllowOverride All and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check your rewrite log by adding these directives :

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog /path/to/logfile
```